# Spelling of revoke

Tags: differences, pronunciation

Why is revoke spelled with a ***k*** (and revoker and revoked/revoking), yet revocable is spelled with a ***c***?

On [this website](https://books.google.com/books?id=xXECAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=why%20is%20revocable%20spelled%20revoc&source=bl&ots=bfqHHVFAej&sig=5DJbungxSJXF1kW2eEZ_14BUtNk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA_vji2bbSAhVPHGMKHe6GB3QQ6AEIPTAF#v=onepage&q=why%20is%20revocable%20spelled%20revoc&f=false), the Latin word **revoc** is the base for "revocable"and "revoke". So why is revoke spelled with a ***k***? Is it to prevent it being pronounced "revose"? If this is so, why is this ***k*** not constant throughout the words?

Thanks!

Comment: I bet it has to do with phonetics. We also have "invoke" and "invocation".

Comment: Perhaps Germanic folk etymology influencing the word?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the vowel(s) following the 'k' or the 'c'.
If there is a weak vowel like 'e', you will use the consonant 'k'. Otherwise by using a 'c', it would no longer have the sound of a 'k'! So there is no 'revoce'!

On the other hand you have 'revocable' with a 'c' before a hard vowel 'a' which does not need a 'k' because 'c' is always spoken like a 'k' with following vowels like a, o or u: vocal, come, cucumber!

Comment: What's a weak vowel?

Comment: But then why not add a *k* in revocable? Why is it revo***c***able?

Comment: @Emereal Why do you demand that English spelling make sense?

Comment: @choster It's a question, not a demand.